# If $X(t)$ is a WSS process with mean 5, what is the mean of $X(2t)$?

Tags: random-process, stochastic, stationary, probability, ergodic

I know mean is constant for a WSS process but I am still confused about the mean for this process. My process was by integrating $X(2t)$ from $0$ to $T$, then substituting $t′=2t$. So the limits become $0$ and $2T$ and $dt=dt′/2$. So putting these substitution, we get same mean for X(2t). Let me know if my approach is correct.

Comment: Homework?  In a very oblique sense, $X(t) = 5$ is wide sense stationary (at least -- no one can point to a statistic of it that is time-dependent).  In this case, what is $X(2t)$?  What is $E\{X(2t)\}$?

Comment: @TimWescott Nope, an exam question. We still haven't received the solutions due to thanksgiving but I just cannot get it out of my mind. Well my process was that integrating $X(2t)$ from 0 to T, then substituting $t' = 2t$. So the limits become 0 and 2T and $dt = dt'/2$. So putting these substitution, we get same mean for $X(2t)$. Let me know if my approach is correct.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to put your work in there -- that'll help people address your specific doubt about what you've done.

Comment: @TimWescott I have edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: How about telling us more explicitly **exactly what** the question being asked is.  Don't paraphrase: we don't need what _you_ understand of the question or stuff like "My process was by integrating ..."  Tell us _exactly_ word-for-word what the _question_ says.  -1 pending appropriate editing

Comment: @AnmolGupta, Could you please review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First, the mean of a random / stochastic process is:

$$ \mu \left( t \right) = \mathbb{E} \left[ X \left( t \right) \right] $$

For WSS we know that $ \mu \left( t \right) = \mu $ but the important thing is that the expectation operator is working on the ensemble per $ t $.

In case the question was, For a given WSS process $ X \left( t \right) $ the mean is $ \mu $ what would be the mean of the process $ X \left( 2 t \right) $ then the answer is trivial as given by [Purdue - ECE 302: Probabilistic Methods in Electrical and Computer Engineering](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ChanGroup/ECE302/) - Stanley Chan - [Lecture A.5 Wide Sense Stationary Processes](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ChanGroup/ECE302/files/Slide_A_05.pdf):

[image]

When we add the Ergodicity property we can start calculating the mean using samples from a single realization (Path). So if you want prove it that way, the path will be trickier. It also assumes the question gave the information the process was ergodic.

I think the actual approach shouldn't be using the definition by integral from the Ergodicity.
As if you go to the integral over time you assume ergodicity which in this case, mentally, came from the fact you assumed $X \left( 2 t \right)$ is a Wide Sense Stationary (WSS) Process (I assume the original process holds mean ergodicity).

It might be that the question assumes or explicitly says something about the behavior of the Auto Correlation function (To prove ergodicity) or in general that the process is ergodic.

If so, what you need to do is to show the new process also holds the WSS and the requirement for ergodicity holds (Taken from [Purdue - ECE 302: Probabilistic Methods in Electrical and Computer Engineering](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ChanGroup/ECE302/) - Stanley Chan - [Lecture A.5 Wide Sense Stationary Processes](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ChanGroup/ECE302/files/Slide_A_05.pdf)):

[image]

It should work in the case of the time scaling in your question.

Comment: All this is fine but the OP hasn't said (and probably has not been told) what $R_Y(\tau)$ is, and thus verification of $(5)$ from your quote is going to be impossible.  The correct answer, that $E[Y(2t)] = E[Y(t)] = \mu$, is immediate from the definition of what WSS means without the necessity of dragging in ergodicity.

Comment: I was aiming to the connection the OP made between the integral over time to the properties of the process. What you wrote is right, it is also explicitly written in the link. I will clarify this in the answer. I just don't think the question was so trivial.